# CSS ids, classes and layouts

Tags: css

[Currently at: http://www.jsfiddle.net/tqtFg  Michael Durrant]
I'm very new to css and I'm trying to create a website with a logo and navigation panel side by side. If you visit the site initially the panel appears out of the 'topcontent', just below and to the right in fact, but if you clicked the logo to go to the same page the panel appears where i'd like it to be!

My Site : http://acews.x10.mx

it seems something is not being intialized when first opened, but I can't tell what. here's my html code;

```
<div id="topcontent">
    <div id="top">
        <a href="index.html">
            <img src="logo.png">
        </a>
        <div id="navbar">
            <ul id="menubar">
                <li class="menuButton"><a href="index.html" class="home">Home</a></li>
                <li class="menuButton"><a href="about.html" >About ACE</a></li>
                <li class="menuButton"><a href="login.html" >Customer Login</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here's my css code;

```
    body {

}

/*Content page divider*/
#topcontent {
    /* margin: 50px auto; */
    height: 170px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    background-image:url('backgroundcolor.png');
}

#top {
    height: 170px;
    width:  900px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}

/* MenuBar */
#navbar {
margin-top:60px;
float:right;
}

ul#menubar {
/* margin:20px; */
list-style:none;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
padding: 5px 10px 0 10px;

}

ul#menubar li {
display:inline;
font-family: calibri;
font-weight: bold;
margin-left:10px;
}

ul#menubar li a {
text-decoration:none;
text-align:center;
padding:5px 10px;
/* width:100px; */
color:#FFFFFF;
float:left;
font-size:26px;
}

.menuButton a:hover{
background-color:#618E00;
text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Hi Robert, I created a jsfiddle for you at:

Comment: You'll need to update url's and references, e.g. background image but this should help you and others diagnose and treat your problem ;)

Comment: Awesome tool, thanks Michael!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add id for link with logo:

```
    <a href="index.html" id="logo">
        <img src="logo.png">
    </a>
```

and CSS

```
#logo {float:left;}
```

link with logo is like one single line, if you add float to it should be ok.

Comment: Cheers Kokers, simple when you know how eh!!